# Polymer on-mouseover not working for child elements

Tags: javascript, polymer

```
<paper-shadow class="card" z="1" animated on-mouseover="{{bringToFront}}" on-mouseout="{{bringToBack}}">
    <p>hello></p>
</paper-shadow> 
<script>
    var scope = document.querySelector('template[is=auto-binding]');
    scope.bringToFront = function(e) {e.target.setZ(2);}; 
    scope.bringToBack = function(e) {e.target.setZ(1);}; 
</script>
```

I am using Polymer Paper Elements

When I mouse over the card the shadow depth will increase, but when I mouse over the paragraph ("hello") the method is not called. How can I let it propagate to my card element?